# How do I set the background color of the editing accessory of a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, colors

My app's theme color is a greenish color, so everything has to be green, like this table view cell:

[image]

The problem is that when I click the Edit button, a little minus sign pops up on the left of the cell and that isn't green:

[image]

I don't understand why this happens. This is my code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
cell.textLabel?.text = someStuff
cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xca / 0xff, green: 1, blue: 0xc7 / 0xff, alpha: 1)
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xca / 0xff, green: 1, blue: 0xc7 / 0xff, alpha: 1)

// Look! here I set the color of the editing accessory!
cell.editingAccessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xca / 0xff, green: 1, blue: 0xc7 / 0xff, alpha: 1)
return cell
```

As you can see, I've set everything to green, including the text label, the background, and even the `editingAccessoryView`! But that thing just isn't green! It stays white as you can see above.

Is there something else I have to set to make that green?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to do it in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. You can it like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "MyText"
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xca / 0xff, green: 1, blue: 0xc7 / 0xff, alpha: 1)
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the visual result of the code above:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The editingAccessoryView background color can be modified like this:

```
cell.contentView.superview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xca / 0xff, green: 1, blue: 0xc7 / 0xff, alpha: 1)
```

If the change of `contentView.superview` background color dont work you can try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xca / 0xff, green: 1, blue: 0xc7 / 0xff, alpha: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have updated my buttons for **Swift 2.2**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
    {
        let deleteBtn = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            print("Delete pressed!")
        })
        deleteBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()//Change color here
        let editBtn = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            print("Edit pressed!")
        })
        editBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()//change color here
        return [deleteBtn, editBtn]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature of this function has changed slightly in subsequent versions of swift.

in Swift 4+ use

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // Your color here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why apple don't put these things in default. Here's the code that change whole UITableViewCell background color:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseId, for: indexPath)
    //Setup selectedbackgroundView which change color includes editingAccessoy background  color
    let selectedBackground = UIView()
    selectedBackground.frame = cellView.frame
    selectedBackground.backgroundColor = SCColor.selectedColor
    cellView.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackground
    //Setup backgroundView which change color includes asscessory background color
    let cellBackground = UIView()
    cellBackground.frame = cellView.frame
    cellBackground.backgroundColor = cellData.isSelected ? SCColor.selectedColor : UIColor.white
    cellView.backgroundView = cellBackground
}
```